# install Dropbox on Ubuntu

Tags: debian, ubuntu, dropbox

I downloaded `dropbox_2020.03.04_amd64.deb` from dropbox.com and install it with `sudo apt install ./dropbox_2020.03.04_amd64.deb`, then I click the app dropbox to install it.

[image]

Dropbox installation windows get stuck at 92% (sometims 92%, 99%), then the process `python3 /usr/bin/dropbox start -i` starts occupying more and more memory til the system couldn't afford. Then the system freezes.

How do I fix this to install Dropbox?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and similar things happen on Debian 11.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work for me on Lubuntu 22.04:

```
# install any dependencies
sudo apt install libpango1.0-0
sudo dpkg -i dropbox_2020.03.04_amd64.deb
```

which produces:

> Dropbox installation successfully completed! You can start Dropbox
> from your applications menu.

then starting Dropbox from the GUI will download some package and run it. Near 97% of completion or so, it will launch a browser (Firefox in my case) with a log-in page for Dropbox.

One note is that I [uninstalled the Snap version of Firefox](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04) and installed the apt version of firefox, as it is said to have some problems:

> ...
> Some third-party integrations are (currently) broken

Comment: It works! Thank you! May I ask how do you find out the missing lib `libpango1.0-0`?

Comment: @Rahn Sure, I just tried `sudo dpkg -i dropbox_2020.03.04_amd64.deb` first, and looked into whatever error message that is/may be returned. On my machine, I got an complaint about a missing package.